# How to add @OnClick from buttom inside a Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, butterknife

I'm using ButterKnife to simplify my life and I have a button inside a LinearLayout  which I would like to include @OnClick annotation on it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        style="@style/PaymentButtonStyle"
        android:text="calncel@string/cancel_label"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

With this layout it complains the button ID isn't found.

```
@OnClick(R.id.cancel_payment_button)
public void onCancelClick(View target) {
        ...
    }
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: `id` in layout is `cancel_button` while what you have declared is `@OnClick(R.id.cancel_payment_button)`

Answer (score 2):

Your id is `cancel_button`, not a `cancel_payment_button`.

And also don't forget to bind ButterKnife with `ButterKnife.bind()` method.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I forgot to edit the name. But error continues.

Comment: Do you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not finding the `button` with the correct `id`, in the layout that you included above there is no `id` for `R.id.cancel_payment_button`, only `R.id.cancel_button.` Also, check if the import for `R` class is correct (following your main package).

Comment: I fix the name. But problems persists